# Converting date factor using as.date in R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a data column from factors to date format but some problem always shows up. The original date column is like below:

```
date
1/01/2008
1/01/2008
1/01/2008
1/01/2008
1/01/2008
```

Look at its first 6 rows

```
head(PowerConsumption)
```

It shows that:

```
$ Date: Factor w/ 729 levels "1/01/2007","1/01/2008",..: 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 189 ...
```

1. Don't quite understand what all these 189 mean?
2. I meant to change factor to date type.

After applying this code:

```
date <- as.Date(PowerConsumption$Date, format = "%d%m%Y")
```

All the values become `NA`. Can anyone point out what's wrong please?

Comment: You have to convert it to a character vector first. Try to wrap `PowerConsumption$Date` in `as.character`: `as.Date(as.character(PowerConsumption$Date), format = "%d%m%Y")`

Comment: can u try this `date <- as.Date(PowerConsumption$Date, format = "%d/%m%/Y")` i.e. `strDates <- c("01/05/1965", "16/08/1975")
dates <- as.Date(strDates, "%d/%m/%Y") `

Comment: Read in / create your original `PowerConsumption` data frame with the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` parameter to avoid this in the future.

Comment: It worked by adding "/". Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First, all those `189`'s mean that the vector starts with values of the 189th level of that factor variable. A simplified example:

```
> x <- factor(c("1/01/2007","1/01/2008","1/01/2007","1/01/2008"))
> str(x)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "1/01/2007","1/01/2008": 1 2 1 2
```

Second, when you want to convert that date variable to a date format, you need to specify the correct format of the originating variable (you omitted the `/` when specifying the format parameter):

```
> as.Date(x, format="%d/%m/%Y")
[1] "2007-01-01" "2008-01-01" "2007-01-01" "2008-01-01"
```

Contrary to what I said in the comments such a factor-variable doesn't necessarily need to be converted to character first with `as.character`.

---

Another option to cenvert the factor values to dates is using the `anydate` function from the new `anytime` package:

```
> library(anytime)
> anydate(x)
[1] "2007-01-01" "2008-01-01" "2007-01-01" "2008-01-01"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments h2rm4n. However, I don't understand why it only starts with the 189th. I don't have any NAs in this column...

Comment: @Sunshine That is because the first dates are all the same and you have 188 dates that are earlier than `2008-01-01`. To get an idea, check the output of `as.integer(PowerConsumption$Date)`.

Comment: @Sunshine I also added an alternative with the `anytime` package.

Answer (score 0):

There is, of course, a `lubridate` solution:

```
x <- factor(c("1/01/2007","1/01/2008","1/01/2007","1/01/2008"))

dmy(x)
#[1] "2007-01-01" "2008-01-01" "2007-01-01" "2008-01-01"
```

Comment: This one looks very simple! Will try it too. Thanks!